# Git - Merge to Master

Tags: eclipse, git, egit

I want to merge what I've done in my develop brach to the master, but the master does not appear in Eclipse merge tool

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you tried to `git fetch` from master?

Comment: You might take a look at Eclipse's team synchronizing perspective. See http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftasks-115.htm EDIT: that link refers to CVS, but Git should work just as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your working tree is yet on branch `develop`, but you need to be on branch `master` if you want to *modify* it. (You will modify it by appending a *merge* commit).

You need first to `checkout` branch `master`, and then merge `develop` into `master`.

If you were doing this with git command-line, that would be:

```
$ git checkout master
$ git merge develop
```

But I'm sure you can find the corresponding functions in Eclipse.

Remember, with Git you can only modify the branch you're sitting on (working tree).

Comment: (I would guess the dropdown below "Branches" in the first screenshot would allow you to switch branches)

Comment: Upvoted for certainly the right idea. His branch seems to be named "develop" though...not "development". BTW..that first screenshot seems to be Atlassian Bitbucket / Stash, so kinda disconnected from Eclipse.